# Evaluating Neural Network using accuracy in Keras model

Tags: neural-network, keras, keras-layer

In Keras, when training and evaluating a Neural Network model (classify two classes (0 and 1)), the model returns loss and accuracy for both training and testing:

```py
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

What does this accuracy represent? Is it the mean accuracy for the two classes or the accuracy for one of the two classes?

Answer (score 3):

Accuracy is the number of correctly classified samples divided by the number of all samples. It does not involve any per class accuracies.

Here is for example the code Keras uses to compute the binary accuracy:

```
K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680984/does-input-dimension-resolution-affect-the-performance-of-convolutional-neural-n/47684223#47684223

Answer (score 1):

Keras will choose from a list of possible metrics in its code. From the [metrics](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py) source code, there are five possibilities:

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)

def categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1),
    K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)),
    K.floatx())

def sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.max(y_true, axis=-1),
    K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), K.floatx())),
    K.floatx())

def top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=5):
    return K.mean(K.in_top_k(y_pred, K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), k), axis=-1)

def sparse_top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=5):
    return K.mean(K.in_top_k(y_pred, K.cast(K.max(y_true, axis=-1), 'int32'), k), axis=-1)
```

The choice depends on what type of model and loss function you have. In the [training](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py) module, you see it choosing the accuracy function:

```
if (output_shape[-1] == 1 or self.loss_functions[i] == losses.binary_crossentropy):
    # case: binary accuracy
    acc_fn = metrics_module.binary_accuracy

elif self.loss_functions[i] == losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy:
    # case: categorical accuracy with sparse targets
    acc_fn = metrics_module.sparse_categorical_accuracy

else:
    acc_fn = metrics_module.categorical_accuracy
```

In your model, you have 2 outputs and a `categorical_crossentropy` loss, so you will fall in case 3, and your accuracy will be:

```
def categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1),
    K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)),
    K.floatx())
```

Translating, your model expects only one class to be true, if the index of the predicted class with maximum value is equal to the index of the true class, it counts as right.

Example:

- predicted: [0.7 ; 0.3] /// true: [1 ; 0] --- counts as right
- predicted: [0.8 ; 0,2] /// true: [0 ; 1] --- counts as wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680984/does-input-dimension-resolution-affect-the-performance-of-convolutional-neural-n/47684223#47684223